# What happens if I switch Bonus Powers?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've got a subset of the bonus powers unlocked, but I've been paranoid about picking one.  If I regret my decision later, I'm not sure what I can do about it.

For instance, picking a power appears to cost 4,000 credits.  If I change my mind, will I have to pay 4,000 credits again to unlock another?  If I want to switch back to the first power, do I have to pay the 4,000 again, or is paying it once per-power sufficient?

Also, what happens to any level-up points I sink into a given bonus power if I switch?  Do I get those points back, or are they applied to the new power in the same way they were applied to the old?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've done this by accident

You have to pay the credits each time you switch, and switching refunds the points you put into the power.

Comment: I did it also by mistake :D